# Moving stored procedure from oracle to sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

```
PROCEDURE populate_boj_deposit_tab(asatdate IN VARCHAR2, in_sol   IN VARCHAR2)   AS 
test_cnt      BINARY_INTEGER; 
startdate     DATE; 
codefound     BINARY_INTEGER := 0; 
counter       BINARY_INTEGER := 0; 
ex_indx       BINARY_INTEGER := 1;  
excludeAcct   BINARY_INTEGER := 1; 
arr_indx      BINARY_INTEGER := 1; 
deposit_table_obj                      deposit_record_table;
category_table_obj    category_record_table;
exclusion_table_obj   exclusion_record_table := exclusion_record_table();
report_array reports := reports();

INSERT /*+ APPEND */ INTO boj_deposit_portfolio
    SELECT 
      customer_id,
      SUM(GENERALFUNCTIONS.FN_ConvertAmountAsOfDate(asAtDate, currency,'JMD',sanctioned_ato,'REV')) AS sanctioned_ato
    FROM 
      boj_raw_accounts_data
    GROUP BY customer_id;

    COMMIT;

    --Find and populate exclusion table
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'TRUNCATE TABLE boj_deposits_exclusion';                    
    --Get loans accounts for each report that does not match    
    SELECT 
    transaction_balance, acid, borrower_category_code, sector_code, sub_sector_code, 
    rep_date, customer_id, cust_code
    BULK COLLECT INTO
    deposit_table_obj
    FROM bojdeposit_tab;
```

How can I convert this code to SQL SERVER I'm new to using Oracle without changing the functionality of the query? I'm okay with the data types and the other general stuff, the main concern is the bulk insert and table objects, for example, category_table_obj    category_record_table;

Comment: You should take a look to SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for Oracle https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/getting-started-with-ssma-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

Almost every line needs to be changed:

```
There is no type ** BINARY_INTEGER  in SQL Server.
Assginment in SQL Server is done with an = sign not a := sign.

You can remove the commit - SQL Server starts a transaction with a begin transaction
General_functions in sql server would be interpreted as a schema name not package.
There is no execute immediate statement in SQL Server or bulk collect statement in SQL Server.
```

There are equivalent statements for all of these in SQL Server but it would require a lot of work (and someone who knows both SQL Server TSQL and Oracle OSQL).